# Can we displace earth?

Tags: gravity, future-missions, time, rotation

From the gravitation equation it is clear the earth gets pulled but we fall due to negligible mass. But, if each and every person on the earth takes a jet-pack and jumps to a height equivalent to 20 to 30 meters at the same instant of time, will the earth have any change in its motion? If yes then what could be the outcomes?

Comment: This is more of a speculative physics question than anything to do with space exploration as currently phrased.

Comment: It's not exactly a jetpack, but the result would be the same: https://what-if.xkcd.com/8/

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely any meaningful effect.  Some napkin math...

Weight of average human: [$62 kg$](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2458-12-439.pd)

Population Estimate:  [$7.4 \times 10^9$](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/)

Mass of combined population: $4.5 \times 10^{11} kg$.

The mass of Earth is [estimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mass) $5.972 \times 10^{24} kg$.

That's a huge order of magnitude in difference, and as such any gravity effects should be barely noticeable.

Comment: Phrased another way, the human population biomass on Earth ($10^{11}$ kg) is to the Earth ($10^{24}$ kg) ***roughly as*** a regular-sized bar of chocolate ($0.1 = 10^{-1}$ kg) is to the human population biomass on Earth ($10^{11}$ kg).

Comment: I'm pretty sure if we rolled every human into a ball and collided it with the earth at 2000km/s we'd basically be able to take out a city, maybe a few cities nothing more.